# How to auto create a custom post when a user purchases a product in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to automatically create a custom post called 'project' when a logged in user purchased a product.
I put the following code on thank you page:

```
function get_last_order_id(){
    global $wpdb;
    $statuses = array_keys(wc_get_order_statuses());
    $statuses = implode( "','", $statuses );

    // Getting last Order ID (max value)
    $results = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT MAX(ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts
        WHERE post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
        AND post_status IN ('$statuses')
    " );
    return reset($results);
}
$latest_order_id = get_last_order_id(); // Last order ID

//Auto creation Project post when user purchased
if (!count($latest_order_id)) {
    return;
} else {
    function programmatically_create_post_after_buying() {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $current_user_id = $current_user->display_name;
        $post_id = wp_insert_post(
              array(
                'author'   => $current_user_id,
                'post_title'    => $current_user_id,
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                'post_type'   => 'project'
             )
        );
    }
    add_filter('after_setup_theme', 'programmatically_create_post_after_buying' );
}
```

The code displays `$latest_order_id` correctly. 
But, it doesn't create a post.
I can't find which parts are wrong, could you please help me? 
I am a complete beginner, so there must be a lot of problems.

Comment: There are many things wrong with your code. 1) If you are in thank you page you don't have to fetch latest order id woocommerce gives you order id on thank you page. 2) you can directly put your code in thankyou page you don't have to add filter for that. Now main thing your code is not working probably your filter is not invoking that time.

Comment: Thank you for your comments but I'm a complete beginner so I can't understand how to edit... It would be a big help if you could provide me the correct code, if possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call 'woocommerce_thankyou' action from woocommerce thank you page. By using it you can get latest order id and create post based on that. You can add this code to your theme's functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'create_post_on_order' );

function create_post_on_order( $order_id ){
    global $wpdb;
    //print('<pre>'.print_r( $wpdb, true ).'</pre>');
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    if( !$order->get_id() ){
        return;
    }

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_id = $current_user->display_name;
    $post_title = $order_id.' - '.$current_user_id;
    // Check post already exit with our title or not
    $query = $wpdb->prepare(
        'SELECT ID FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . '
        WHERE post_title = %s
        AND post_type = \'project\'',
        $post_title
    );
    $wpdb->query( $query );

    if ( !$wpdb->num_rows ) {
        $post_id = wp_insert_post(
            array(
                'author'   => $current_user_id,
                'post_title'    => $post_title,
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                'post_type'   => 'project'
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Note : You have to create post title unique so you can identify post based on order.

Comment: Hi Gautam: Wow, it works perfectly. Thank you a lot for your kind help and I learnt a lot from you : ) I'm sorry but can I ask one more question? There is a custom acf field (field name ‘ponum’) in the project post. Do you know how to update the order number to the acf field? I tried  'ponum'   => $order_id but it doesn’t update the field. I'm sure I'm on the wrong way...

Comment: Add this line `update_post_meta( $post_id, 'ponum', $order_id );`

Comment: @Gautam Golakiya : I soved it. Thank you again for your big help : )

Comment: @Bhautik : Thank you for your help : )